# how to have long lived docusign embedded signing url in power automate

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, docusignapi, power-automate

We are using DocuSign connectors in Power Automate to send documents for signature to recipients. I am using the "Generate embedded signing URL" connector. However, this link will expire once the recipient opens and closes the browser. If they reopen the URL, it shows the DocuSign page and indicates that the link has expired.

how to have long lived docusign embedded signing url in power automate

Answer (score 0):

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/long-lived-embedded-signing-urls this old blog post talks about this, but for security reasons, you can't just get a long-lived URL by just asking for one.

You have to build some code and you need some infrastructure around that code to accomplish this.

Basically what you do is create your own URLs with some type of mechanism to know which envelope/recipient they refer to (if you only have one recipient per envelope - you just need the enveloped)

So the click goes to your URL (you can do serverless with Azure/AWS, or have a server or have some other way to have that) and then runs your code, your code will make the API call to generate the DocuSign URL and redirect the user to that URL, that's how it works, so the URL is always fresh.